Using mget -r * for sftp to copy around 5L files effectively and faster? how to do?
we are using sftp where client dropping around 4L files (almost pdf files).
Now I want to copy from sftp to my host NAS mounted drive called "/project/data/"
I used mget -r * , but while running script, it only stuck at this , until fully copied which is taking almost 10-12hrs copying 550gb of data (4L files).
How do I perform this with proper logging and effectively, making sure no duplication copy in case we run script again?
Below is my snippet, but it does not log each file being copied, means nothing is printed
    # Function to perform SFTP transfer and log each file being copied
sftp_transfer() {
    sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" sftp -P "$PORT" "$SOURCE" <<EOF | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
    lcd $DESTINATION
    mget -r *
    bye
EOF
}


rsync can run over ssh (idk about sftp in particular) and can parallelize and do idempotency checks
